# Bar Chart shape mismatch

Tags: python

I got this assignment about plotting a bar graph and a scatter plot using some excel sheet. The scatter plot works fine, but for some reason the bar graph is giving the shape mismatch error and I can't seem to figure out why, since I did the code a few days ago it seemed to work.
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_excel('Salaries.xlsx',sheet_name='Salaries', header=1)

xl=[2,3,4]
y1=[5,5,5]
x2=[1,2,3,4,5]
y2=[2,3,2,3,4]
y3=[6,8,7,8,7]
plt.scatter(xl,y1)
plt.scatter(x2,y2,marker='s',color='r')
plt.scatter(x2,y3,marker='*',color='green')
plt.title('Scatter Plot Example')
plt.show

y1=[4,7,2,4,7,8,3]
x2=[2,4,6,8,10]
y2=[5,6,5,6,2]
plt.bar(xl,y1, label="Blue Bar", alpha=0.2, color='b')
plt.bar(x2,y2, label="Green Bar", alpha=0.3, color='g')
plt.plot()
plt.xlabel("Bar Number")
plt.ylabel("Bar Height")
plt.title("Bar Chart Test")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It gives an error on the bar chart graph^, I'll attach a screenshot. Please help me fix this, Thank you

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUiXX.png)

Comment: Hi. When showing outputs, code, or similar things, it's better to use `formatted code blocks`. You can edit your question for that.

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you've redefined only your y1, meaning your x1 is 3 long and your y1 is 7 long. This is the source of your dimension mistmatch.

Comment: I did the same thing on my last code, it seemed to plot the bar graph perfectly. It won't work now for some reason,  I have sent an image link for you to see.  https://imgur.com/a/YNilC0P

Comment: Figured it out, thank you very much